# How to call compat_ioctl or unlocked_ioctl?

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I'm trying to implement a driver for RTC (Real Time Clock). I used `ioctl` function in `kernel  2.6.32`. It worked fine. But when I run same driver in kernel 3.13.0, it gave an error `‘struct file_operations’ has no member named ‘ioctl’`

when I changed `ioctl` to `unlocked_ioctl` and `compat_ioctl`, compiled and moduled inserted.

But calling `ioctl` in user application **not invoking `ioctl` function** in module. What function I have to use in user application to invoke `compat_ioctl` or `unlocked_ioctl`?

Comment: verify with arguments of unlocked_ioctl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Check with arguments in driver**

define structure file operation Definition like

```
static struct file_operations query_fops =
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_close,
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,35))
    .ioctl = my_ioctl
#else
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl
#endif
};
```

Define ioctl like

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,35))
static int my_ioctl(struct inode *i, struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
#else
static long my_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
        #endif
    {
              switch(cmd){
                ....................................
                ...................................
              }
    }
```

and application level

No need to do any modification you can follow the basic rule for ioctl at application level.

Comment: giving `error: missing binary operator before token "("`

Comment: are u able to insert the module ??? where exactly you are getting the error application side or driver side ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include `linux/version.h`.

Comment: I suggest to use macro as below instead of version check, `#ifdef HAVE_UNLOCKED_IOCTL ....  #endif`